# Street Bearing from Google API?

Tags: google-api

Kind of what it says on the tin: is there an API method, anywhere in the Google Maps/Directions/Geocoding APIs, that gives the bearing of a street relative to north when given a PlaceID? I've already tried `maps/api/place/details`, but it doesn't seem to contain the information I want.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

Try this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood4&
```

Comment: Unfortunately not - I'm not looking for directions, but a compass bearing for some particular segment of street.